# Menubar and side bar not showing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I accidently remove the wine with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*
```

And now I am stucked. I cant see my menubar and side bar on my ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

There are some possible things you've done wrong, please specify the output of the terminal when you removed Wine from your computer.

However, this might also work:

1. Open the terminal by clicking `Ctrl+Alt+T` .
2. Enter `dconf reset`.
3. Enter `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` to reset your desktop. (This will also reset your desktop configuration.)
4. Enter `compiz --replace & disown` to restart your desktop.

You can also look at the settings you have:
`dconf dump /org/compiz/`

It is also possible that you removed the packages for the menubar and sidebar. In this case, you have to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.

1. Open the terminal by clicking `Ctrl+Alt+T` .
2. Enter `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.

If pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T` doesn't open the terminal, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to start your bash, login with your username and password, and input the above code.

If terminal says command "dconf" not found, install dconf-tools by entering:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Hopefully this will help you get back your desktop.

**Edit:**

Since you can't connect to the internet, here's what you should do:

For LAN internet connection, do the following in the bash:

1. `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
2. Replace everything with:

   `auto eth0`

   `iface eth0 inet dhcp`
3. Press `Ctrl+X` then `Y` then `Enter`.
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59103/discussion-on-answer-by-cynplytholowazy-menubar-and-side-bar-not-showing-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity 
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and congrats on your first answer here! I have one criticism though: Why `sudo dconf ...`? That will likely mess with the access permissions on the per-user Dconf database. It would be better to run it without super-user privileges. If you ran into access permission issues as a regular user it would be better to fix those in the first place. -1

Comment: @David Why you dont ask the Question starter how its possible to accidently use sudo ?? As this answer stated, IT WORKED. Let me answer your question.. A regular user should not even need to worry about these commands. PS:

Comment: @An0n: I don't understand how that relates to my comment. Whether a user should run a command is irrelevant once they did. And why should *I* ask the OP? Why don't *you*?